# Angular Validation for input depends on another input

Tags: html, json, angularjs

I have a list of json objects. Each object has `minage` and `maxage`.

I want to `ng-repeat` on this object and display input to enter the `minAge` and input for `maxAge`.

I want to add validation for the fields:

- Max age should be bigger than Min age.
- the Min age of the next pair
  of inputs should be lower than Max age of previous pair of inputs.

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avime3156/am9u11sw/2/)

Comment: the ìnput` tag is an angular js `directive` you can find all you need here : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D

Comment: the first validation can you writh:  <input type="number" ng-model="range.MaxAge"  min="{{range.MinAge}}"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `min` and `max` arguments within your inputs to achieve this:

```
<div ng-repeat="range in ages">
    minAge: <input type="number" min="{{ages[$index-1]['MaxAge']}}" max="{{range.MaxAge}}" ng-model="range.MinAge" />

    maxAge: <input type="number" min="{{range.MinAge}}" ng-model="range.MaxAge" />
</div>
```

Comment: 10x.Thats what I need! but :for the first minAge I dont have any value in :ages[$index-1]['MaxAge'] , How can I check if no value, and put min=0 ?

Comment: @BrMe I think you can use something like this: `{{range.MaxAge ? range.MaxAge : null}}`

Comment: This is work for me :{{ages[$index-1].MaxAge || 0 }}